# "Help" tab in Eclipse IDE changes as I move cursor in code editor

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, settings

I have the Help tab open in Eclipse IDE.  As I move my cursor around the code editor, the Help tab updates to show a relevant link to the code at the cursor.  I can click on a link and it opens the Javadoc.  If I move my cursor in the code editor, then the Help tab updates to show a relevant link.  This is annoying.  I would like to read the Javadoc while I am typing code.

How do I configure the Help tab to stay on the Javadoc until I press F1?

Edit: One comment suggested that I click on the "Link with Selection" button.  I do not have said button on my screen.  See this screenshot.

[image]

Comment: You mean the _Javadoc_ view. Disable _Link with selection_: https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/ref-view-javadoc.htm (toggle button at the top of this view)

Comment: @howlger I do not have that button on my screen.  See the screenshot I added to the question.

Comment: I see, not the _Javadoc_ but the _Help_ view, as you said. Yes, that's the context-sensitive help. Use _Help > Help Contents_ to open the help in a separate window.

Comment: @howlger I do not want a separate window.  I want the Help view in a tab.

Comment: The non context-sensitive help will be shown in a separate window or in an external web browser for reasons and whether you want it or not.